# How to add a Rate button for android AIR application AS3

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, flashdevelop, flash-cs6

Hey everyone so I created a Android Applications Using Flash CS6 and Flash Develop. I have searched everywhere through all threads but can't find anything for Android.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Just want to create a button and if they click it then it will redirect them to rate the game on the google play store.

Please any help will be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of our distriqt extensions to do this. You need a native extension to be able to launch the appropriate native Intent to get the

http://distriqt.com/native-extensions#applicationrater

Comment: Thanks for the Link. I wish I could afford that but $150 is too much since all I need is the rate button

Comment: I think they'll be going on sale individually this week as well. Not sure on the price of the rater extension yet but it will be considerably cheaper than the package I'd expect.